# Unable to refresh a local table created from linked table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am new to access database.

I created a linked table (linked to an excel file)

I them created a local table which is just a filtered table from the linked table. (same table just filtered for some records.)

The issue I am running into is that I am not able to refresh this local filtered table. The steps I am following are :

1. Refresh linked table using 'linked table manager'
2. Refresh the local table (filtered version of linked table) using linked table manager and the refresh button in the menu bar.

While my linked table gets refreshed, this filtered table does not get refreshed.

Can someone suggest what I can do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your local table is an actual local table (how exactly did you create it?), then it is a new entity with a copy of the data, and changes in the linked table won't be reflected in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a query rather then your local, filtered, table.

Comment: Thanks Rene. This solution worked for me. However, I am trying to append the result of this query from linked table to another such filtered table (created from another linked table). The proble is that the append query asks for a table name and I am unabble to append data from one query to another. ANy suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current structure try this

Create -> Query Design -> click on SQL on the bottom right -> paste the following code in

```
SELECT * INTO local_filtered_table
FROM linked_table
WHERE <put your conditions here>;
```

Then run this query each time you update your linked table.

Or you can do as Rene suggested and just make a query instead of a local table which would look something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM linked_table
WHERE <put your conditions here>;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Rene. This solution worked for me. However, I am trying to append the result of this query from linked table to another such filtered table (created from another linked table). The proble is that the append query asks for a table name and I am unabble to append data from one query to another. ANy suggestion?

Comment: Thanks I think I solved the second problem by using Union query